# How do I detect 50kHz echsounder in PAMGuard

Tags: pamguard, pam, echosounder, porpoise

I have collected a large (~10TB) dataset using SoundTraps recording at 576kHz to investigate harbour porpoise foraging behaviour around fishing nets.

I processed the data using PAMGuard's click detector module (v2.02.02) running the default porpoise classifier to detect porpoise clicks. Using PAMGuard's datagram to visualise the click detections, there appear to be a large number of 50kHz pulses with harmonics in the porpoise frequency band (100-150kHz) (see example screenshot below) that are almost certainly echosounders.

[image: Example of echosounders detected by PAMGuard's click detection module]
*Example of echosounders detected by PAMGuard's click detection module*

It is important we remove these sections of data as 50kHz echosounder may alter porpoise behaviour, however, the dataset is far too large to manually remove each echosounder encounter. Is there a way to automatically detect 50kHz echosounder in PAMGuard?

Answer (score 3):

The best way to do this is to use the click detector's in-built classifier. Open the classifier settings (*Settings-> Click Detector -> Click Classification*) and create a new classifier (make sure it's the classifier with frequency sweep and not the basic classifier).

There is already a porpoise classifier and we want the echosounder classifier to exclude a click before it might be mis-classified as a porpoise so it needs to be the first classifier in the list (use the *up* button).

Next, set up the classifier to detect a peak frequency of between 48 and 50 kHz. The key distinguishing feature of many echosounders is the narrow bandwidth so set that to no more than around 15kHz. Re-process the clicks in viewer mode and now echosounders will be automatically detected!

[image: Settings for creating an echosounder classifier in PAMGaurd]

*Settings for creating an echosounder classifier in PAMGaurd - note clicks detections classified as echosounder are blue*

Finally use the [MATLAB or R library](https://www.pamguard.org/48_MATLABRcode.html) to extract the clicks from PAMGaurd binary files - if there more than XX classified echosounders in a time bin then that section of data can be excluded from further analysis which will (hopefully) reduce any bias from echosounders influencing porpoise behaviour.

Comment: thanks, didn't realize the prioritization of different classifications. Can a click ever be classified by 2 classifiers (or can it be set to do so in Pamguard)?

Comment: Yes, you can click "Save Classifier Set" in the click classification settings dialog. Then the results for each classifier are saved to the binary files.

Comment: Hey @JamieMacaulay - I thought your test band and control bands could not overlap but see you have all starting at "0" in your example. Was I incorrect in thinking there needs to be a difference in these bands?

Comment: Hi @LizFerg - yes you can use any  overlapping bands , including the same ones if you wish.

Comment: Learn something every day with PAMGuard!

Answer (score 2):

A cheap/dirty way to address this would be to run your automated click detector, and then take advantage of the regular timing of the echosounder pulses by finding the time/sample # of the first pulse, and then removing all following click detections at multiples of the inter-pulse-interval.

Answer (score 1):

I am for sure no pamguard expert, but given that there is very little spectral overlap between porp clicks and 50 and 200 kHz echosounder pulses, it seems that band pass filtering prior to detection should do the job of finding the echosounder pulses?

Comment: I should have explained that the echosounder has harmonics in the porpoise frequency band. I have amended the question.