# Echosounder setting off automated whistle detector in PAMGuard - Help!

Tags: analysis, pamguard, whistles, echosounder, detection

I have underwater acoustic recordings and am interested in marking out dolphin whistles. I am currently having to manually remove an echosounder (which has a bit of a sweep to it), as I do not want my detector to log this as a dolphin whistle.

- Is there a way to do this in [PAMGuard](https://www.pamguard.org/)?
- Am I able to build an
  automated whistle detector for the echosounder signal itself? If so, how?
- How do I ensure that this makes it so the echosounder pings
  are not labelled as being both a dolphin whistle and an echosounder?

This question is related to this previously asked question ([How do I detect 50kHz echsounder in PAMGuard](https://bioacoustics.stackexchange.com/questions/236/how-do-i-detect-50khz-echsounder-in-pamguard)), but in this case, a pesky echosounder is setting off my **automated whistle detector** in PAMGuard (rather than a click detector, as was the case of the previous question).

Thanks!

Comment: Can you provide a screenshot?

Answer (score 4):

I think your best bet may bet may be to use PG to build an echosounder detector, and then use R/Matlab to remove the timeframes that the echosounder exists in.  This will cut out a bit of the time you're taking to remove them manually. Then, you can process your WM detector with the filtered data.  It isn't elegant. However, outside of creating a bandstop filter at your echosounder frequency range (which may remove whistles and moans), I'm not sure if you can do everything you need to do in one run.

Comment: I would call the suggested method (echosounder detector) as the most elegant method, as it does not manipulate the data. If one starts selective filtering then lot of uncertainties can arise